# How do I output .xml file console result into a file?

Tags: java, xml

I am working on a project which involves parsing this sample .xml file (as shown below) but however I didn't get the expected output. When I run this code below it has a different console output than what was in the output of "parseout.xml" The output file "parseout.xml" had the same original file content. How do I go about exporting the console output into a different xml file?

The sample file (note after my code it still outputs this into "parseout.xml" which is the output .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schedule id="backup" duration="86400">
    <datapoint time="0" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="8" concurrencynoise="1" interval="300" intervalnoise="300"/> <!-- 12am -->
    <datapoint time="7200" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="8" concurrencynoise="1" interval="300" intervalnoise="300"/> <!-- 2am -->
    <datapoint time="7201" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="0" concurrencynoise="0" interval="300" intervalnoise="300"/> <!-- 2:00:01am -->
    <datapoint time="86399" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="0" concurrencynoise="0" interval="10" intervalnoise="0"/>  <!-- 11:59:59pm -->
</schedule>
```

The code:

```
File fXmlFile = new File(originalfile.xml);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

// System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("datapoint");

// System.out.println("----------------------------");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    // System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("Time:" + eElement.getAttribute("time"));
        System.out.println("Speed:" + eElement.getAttribute("speed"));
        System.out.println("SpeedNoise:" + eElement.getAttribute("speednoise"));
        System.out.println("Concurrency:" + eElement.getAttribute("concurrency"));
        System.out.println("ConcurrencyNoise:" + eElement.getAttribute("concurrencynoise"));
        System.out.println("Interval: " + eElement.getAttribute("interval"));
        System.out.println("IntervalNoise: " + eElement.getAttribute("intervalnoise"));

        //Using transformer for output
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("parseout.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the `catch` block from your code as there was no matching `try` and it didn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Your console output isn't XML. It's not clear why you'd expect `parseout.xml` to be different to the original given that you're just transforming the original doc. (Note that you're writing it out multiple times for no obvious reason, too...)

Comment: I've tried to output the parseout.xml as text but it didn't work for me too :( @JonSkeet

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't explain what you wanted or what happened.

Comment: I meant it didn't save in this format according to my code into the parseout.xml file as follows:

time=0 
speed=1
speednoise=5
concurrency=8 
concurrencynoise=1
interval=300
intervalnoise=300

This was being displayed in my console output but not my output file parseout.xml

Comment: That's not XML - and why would you *expect* it to be saved to parseout.xml? Which bit of your code do you think is doing that?

Comment: But even when I save it as a text file it still doesn't give me my expected result

Comment: Well that's code you haven't shown, so I can't really comment on it...